# Как сделать выбор файла и/или папки QFileDialog?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-designer, qfiledialog

Как я могу поставить на кнопку действие выбора либо файла, либо папки.
Есть варианты:

```
QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()
QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
```

А как сделать так, чтобы можно было выбрать или папку, или файл?

---

И еще хотелось бы узнать, можно ли при использовании `QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()` сделать, чтобы показывало только файлы определенного расширения?

**front.py**:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 400)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 400))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 400))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnBrowse = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnBrowse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 131, 23))
        self.btnBrowse.setObjectName("btnBrowse")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 131, 151))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.btnArch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnArch.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 180, 81, 23))
        self.btnArch.setObjectName("btnArch")
        self.extractButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.extractButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 0, 81, 23))
        self.extractButton.setObjectName("extractButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btnBrowse.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать папку"))
        self.btnArch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Архивировать"))
        self.extractButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Извлечь"))
```

**main.py**:

```py
import front
import sys, os, zipfile, traceback
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, front.Ui_MainWindow):
    directory = ''

    def __init__(self):
        # Это здесь нужно для доступа к переменным, методам
        # и т.д. в файле design.py
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # Это нужно для инициализации дизайна
        self.btnBrowse.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)
        self.btnArch.clicked.connect(self.arch_folder)
        self.extractButton.clicked.connect(self.extract)

    def browse_folder(self):
        self.listWidget.clear()  # На случай, если в списке уже есть элементы
        self.directory = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Выберите папку")


        if self.directory:  # не продолжать выполнение, если пользователь не выбрал директорию
            for file_name in os.listdir(self.directory):  # для каждого файла в директории
                self.listWidget.addItem(file_name)  # добавить файл в listWidget
        return self.directory

    def arch_folder(self):
        archive = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w')
        dirfiles = os.listdir(self.directory)
        for file in dirfiles:
            try:
                archive.write(self.directory+"/"+file, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
            except:
                print(traceback.format_exc())
        archive.close()

    def extract(self):
        self.archive = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Выберите архив")
        zip_arch = zipfile.ZipFile(self.archive[0], 'r')
        for files in zip_arch.namelist():
            zip_arch.extract(files)
        zip_arch.close()



def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = ExampleApp()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()  # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()  # и запускаем приложение


if __name__ == '__main__':  # Если запускаем файл напрямую, а не импортируем
    main()  # то запускаем функцию main()
```

Comment: Все можно. Опубликуйте свой пример, где вы это все будите делать.

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: Все написано в документации https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys 
import os 
import zipfile
import traceback
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#import front
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 400)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 400))
#        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 400))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnBrowse = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnBrowse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 131, 23))
        self.btnBrowse.setObjectName("btnBrowse")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 331, 151))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.btnArch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnArch.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 180, 81, 23))
        self.btnArch.setObjectName("btnArch")
        self.extractButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.extractButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 0, 81, 23))
        self.extractButton.setObjectName("extractButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btnBrowse.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать ..."))
        self.btnArch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Архивировать"))
        self.extractButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Извлечь"))


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):                                                   # +++
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Сделайте выбор:")
        self.rbDir = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('directory', self)
        self.rbPath = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('pathFile', self)
        btnOk = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Ok", clicked=self.hide)

        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(label, 0, 0, 1, 3)        
        layout.addWidget(self.rbDir, 1, 1, 1, 1) 
        layout.addWidget(self.rbPath, 2, 1, 1, 1) 
        layout.addWidget(btnOk, 3, 2, 1, 1) 


#class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, front.Ui_MainWindow):
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    directory = ''
    pathFile = ''                                                                  # +++

    def __init__(self):
        # Это здесь нужно для доступа к переменным, методам
        # и т.д. в файле design.py
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # Это нужно для инициализации дизайна
        self.btnBrowse.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)
        self.btnArch.clicked.connect(self.arch_folder)
        self.extractButton.clicked.connect(self.extract)

        self.dialog = Dialog()                                                     # +++

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def browse_folder(self):
        self.directory, self.pathFile = '', ''
        self.dialog.exec_()
        if self.dialog.rbDir.isChecked():
            print(f'dialog')
            self.listWidget.clear()  # На случай, если в списке уже есть элементы
            self.directory = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Выберите папку")


            if self.directory:  # не продолжать выполнение, если пользователь не выбрал директорию
                for file_name in os.listdir(self.directory):  # для каждого файла в директории
                    self.listWidget.addItem(file_name)        # добавить файл в listWidget
        elif self.dialog.rbPath.isChecked():
            print(f'rbPath')
            self.pathFile, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
                                                self, 
                                                'Open File', './', 
                                                'Files (*.py *.txt *.log)')
            if self.pathFile:
                self.listWidget.addItem(self.pathFile)        # добавить файл в listWidget

        else:
            print(f'no')
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message', 'Вы ничего не выбрали.')

# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            


    def arch_folder(self):
        print(f'def arch_folder(self): directory = `{self.directory}`')
        print(f'def arch_folder(self): pathFile = `{self.pathFile}`')
        '''
        archive = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w')
        dirfiles = os.listdir(self.directory)
        for file in dirfiles:
            try:
                archive.write(self.directory+"/"+file, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
            except:
                print(traceback.format_exc())
        archive.close()
        '''

    def extract(self):
        print(f'def extract(self): directory = `{self.directory}`')
        print(f'def extract(self): pathFile = `{self.pathFile}`')

        '''
        self.archive = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Выберите архив")
        zip_arch = zipfile.ZipFile(self.archive[0], 'r')
        for files in zip_arch.namelist():
            zip_arch.extract(files)
        zip_arch.close()
        '''

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = ExampleApp()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()  # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()  # и запускаем приложение

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Если запускаем файл напрямую, а не импортируем
    main()  # то запускаем функцию main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нет, я имел ввиду чтобы можно было выбрать с одной менюшки, как в оригинальном винраре, например

Comment: @ClarkDevlin я не совсем понимаю, что вы хотите сделать, попробуйте объяснить лучше.

Comment: Чтобы я нажимал на условное "выбрать" открывалось сразу окно выбора файла, но в нем я мог выбрать, как файл, так и папку. Это возможно?

Answer (score 1):

> Чтобы я нажимал на условное "выбрать" открывалось сразу окно выбора файла,
> но в нем я мог **выбрать, как файл, так и папку**. Это возможно ?

`QFileDialog` не позволяет этого изначально.
Единственное решение - создать свой собственный `getOpenFilesAndDirs`.

Обратите внимание, что для достижения этого вы не можете использовать собственные диалоги вашей ОС, так как Qt почти не контролирует их,
это причина флага `dialog.DontUseNativeDialog`, который является обязательным.

Следующий код работает так же, как и **статические методы**,
и возвращает выбранные элементы (или ни одного, если диалог отменен).

```
import sys 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 400)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 400))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnBrowse = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnBrowse.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 131, 23))
        self.btnBrowse.setObjectName("btnBrowse")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 331, 151))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.btnArch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnArch.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 180, 81, 23))
        self.btnArch.setObjectName("btnArch")
        self.extractButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.extractButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 0, 81, 23))
        self.extractButton.setObjectName("extractButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btnBrowse.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать ..."))
        self.btnArch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Архивировать"))
        self.extractButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Извлечь"))


def getOpenFilesAndDirs(parent=None, caption='', directory='', 
                        filter='', initialFilter='', options=None):
    def updateText():
        # обновить содержимое виджета редактирования строки выбранными файлами
        selected = []
        for index in view.selectionModel().selectedRows():
            selected.append('"{}"'.format(index.data()))
        lineEdit.setText(' '.join(selected))

    dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(parent, windowTitle=caption)
    dialog.setFileMode(dialog.ExistingFiles)
    if options:
        dialog.setOptions(options)
    dialog.setOption(dialog.DontUseNativeDialog, True)            # !!!
    if directory:
        dialog.setDirectory(directory)
    if filter:
        dialog.setNameFilter(filter)
        if initialFilter:
            dialog.selectNameFilter(initialFilter)

    # по умолчанию, если каталог открыт в режиме списка файлов, 
    # QFileDialog.accept() показывает содержимое этого каталога, 
    # но нам нужно иметь возможность "открывать" и каталоги, как мы можем делать с файлами, 
    # поэтому мы просто переопределяем `accept()` с реализацией QDialog по умолчанию, 
    # которая просто вернет `dialog.selectedFiles()`

    dialog.accept = lambda: QtWidgets.QDialog.accept(dialog)

    # в неродном диалоге есть много представлений элементов, 
    # но те, которые отображают фактическое содержимое, создаются внутри QStackedWidget; 
    # это QTreeView и QListView, и дерево используется только тогда, 
    # когда viewMode установлен на QFileDialog.Details, что не в этом случае.
    
    stackedWidget = dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QStackedWidget)
    view = stackedWidget.findChild(QtWidgets.QListView)
    view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(updateText)

    lineEdit = dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit)
    # очищаем содержимое строки редактирования всякий раз, когда изменяется текущий каталог
    dialog.directoryEntered.connect(lambda: lineEdit.setText(''))

    dialog.exec_()
    return dialog.selectedFiles()
    

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  
        
        self.btnBrowse.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)
        self.btnArch.clicked.connect(self.arch_folder)
        self.extractButton.clicked.connect(self.extract)
       
    def browse_folder(self):
        selected_files = getOpenFilesAndDirs()
        print(selected_files) 
        if selected_files:
            self.listWidget.addItems(selected_files)
        else:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message', 'Вы ничего не выбрали.')

    def arch_folder(self):
        print(f'Выполнить Архивирование: ...')

    def extract(self):
        print(f'Что-то Извлечь:  ...')


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    window = ExampleApp()  
    window.show()  
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ClarkDevlin что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу только на часть вопроса. У метода QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName() есть именованный параметр filter, который отвечает за то, чтобы пользователю показывали файлы только нужных расширений. Например, в этом диалоге:

```
QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Выбрать картинку', '', filter='Картинка 
(*.jpg);;Картинка (*.png);;Все файлы (*)')[0]
```

Пользователь сможет увидеть:

1. Или только файлы с расширением .jpg
2. Или только файлы с расширением .png
3. Или файлы всех расширений

Выбрать любой из этих вариантов пользователь сможет в выпадающем списке, расположенном в правом нижнем углу (По крайней мере в ОС Windows)

[image: выпадающий список]

Если нужно, чтобы сразу были видны файлы не одного, а нескольких расширений, то при описании фильтра необходимо в скобках через пробел указывать несколько расширений в следующем формате: (*.(расширение))

Пример:

```
QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Выбрать картинку', '', filter='Картинка 
(*.jpg *.png *.jpeg))[0]
```